# Is it possible to set up devTools workspace in chrome with Salesforce/lightning metadata?

Tags: javascript, lightning, chrome

I'm curently working on some javascript in lightning and it would be so much faster if I could just setup a workspace in chrome devtools so the changes are reflected in the page immediately. Is this possible?

Example here: https://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/

Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow

I have tried using:
"file:///users/ja.name/sfdc2/src/pages/ProductCatalog.page" as the URL. This is a visualforce page containing lightning components. This does not work though.

Thanks

Comment: Search for your lightning component file instead of visualforce page

Comment: This doesn’t work either unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you put the line "debugger;" in the javascript and open dev tools it will stop on the line of code when the method that has debugger in it is fired which should make it easier to find the source file.

I would also advise typing "session settings" into setup search and uncheck "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" this will make it so changes you save in a lightning component are reflected immediately after refresh.  I realize this doesn't allow for real time changes but it at least makes it so you don't have to refresh multiple time for your updates to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks Calvin, I can’t mark this is an answer as it doesn’t solve the problem but it’s certainly very helpful 